# $.ajax call not executing

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I have to make a query to an API via `$.ajax`. I have tons of those queries in my website, all respecting the same pattern.

I only have one that doesn't want to fire and I really don't understand why.

Here is the code of my function :

```
static create(handleResponse) {

        console.log('starting creating product');

        let settings = {
            "url": apiURL + "/relsalesorderproducts/",
            "method": "POST ",
            "headers": {
                "token": localStorage.getItem('ms-token'),
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            }
        };

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log('created product');
            handleResponse(response);
        });
    }
```

I don't see the log 'created product' in the console, I do see the 'starting creating product' log but I don't even see the request being made in the Network section of Developer tools like I do on every other requests, just nothing.

What do you guys think could cause that?

Comment: Stupid question, any errors in the JS console? Have you imported the jQuery lib?

Comment: why stupid and why being agressive? Of course I imported jQuery and no errors in JS console, I wouldn't ask this question if there was

Comment: My question was a stupid question, no aggression, I was just trying to help. Any errors in console?

Comment: @MattClark sorry man. No errors anywhere sadly

Comment: you have an error this: "method": "POST "

Comment: Can you console log the value of `apiURL` and make sure it is scoped correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may just be that you have a space in `"POST "`

Comment: god, thanks so much man, that's the last thing I was thinking about peace